# How can I change my existing Thread.sleep() to alarm manager

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

Right now I use thread.sleep(3000) and print the data in log for every 3 seconds but now I want to change it to 15 minutes. 
WHats the best to use? 
Is it alarm manager or handler ?

Comment: alarmmanager, definitely

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
thread.sleep(1000*60*15)
```

Comment: I want to eliminate thread.sleep and user alarm manager or handler